# @Html.DropDownListFor error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a function that returns

```
> IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListItems
    {
```

using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( m=>Model.listItems) I am having the error message
```

> Error 1   No overload for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 arguments

However, it works fine with `@Html.DropDownList("listItems", Model.listItems)`

Why am I having the error message with  @Html.DropDownListFor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no overloads that satisfy those parameters. In other words, there's no method for Html.DropDownListFor() that accepts just a SelectListItem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor.aspx

Try something like this:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public SelectList YourSelectList { get; set; }
     public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c=>c.SelectedItem, Model.YourSelectList)
```

When your form is posted, SelectedItem will hold whichever item was selected in the dropdown list.